# Trigger event when function is called

Tags: javascript, events, raphael

I am looking for a way of firing events when a transform function is called in Raphaeljs for specific raphael objects. Here is what I have come up with so far.

```
var paper = new Raphael( 0, 0, 1000, 1000 );
var rect = paper.rect( 100, 100, 100, 100 );
var rect1 = paper.rect( 0, 0, 100, 100 );

rect.transform = ( function() {
    var original = rect.transform;

    return function( ) {
         // fire event for rect
        return original.apply( this, arguments );
    }
})();

rect1.transform = ( function() {
    var original = rect1.transform;

    return function( ) {
        // fire event for rect1   
        return original.apply( this, arguments );
    }
})();

rect.transform( "s2" ); // event for rect.transform fired
rect1.transform( "s2" ); // event for rect1.transform fired
```

I just wondered if anyone else knows of any other ways of doing this.

Fiddle of my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/mE5pf/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You could do that for all elements by extending the element prototype, see http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.el for details.